# oracle datafile autoextend

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to ask oracle to autoextend a tablespace datafile when the size hits a defined threshold? If my datafile size is 1G, and autoextend is enabled, can I start growing the file when the usage reaches 900M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Oracle won't extend the data file until it has actually used all the available space in the data file.

Can you take a step back, though, and explain the problem that you're trying to solve?  If you've set your data files to autoextend, you would normally then not monitor how much space is free within the data file itself and would monitor the space available on the file system (and how close the file is to the maximum size if you specify a maximum size).  If you're monitoring the free space in the data file, you would normally not set the data file to autoextend.  I'm a bit hard-pressed to understand why you would want the data file to autoextend and to ensure that there was a certain amount of free space in the data file.

Comment: Someone has implemented pager alarms based on the free space on the data file. When we grow to 95%, they get beeped and they just wanted to know if we can autoextend at 90% :)

Comment: If that's what they're paging on, they shouldn't be autoextending the data files.  If they do want to autoextend the data files, a file that is 100% full but not close to its maximum size on a file system that has plenty of free space shouldn't be cause for alarm.